# Using ngRoute with 'controller as' syntax in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-controlleras

I have the following `config` and `controllers`

```
.config(function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'page-home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'hctrl'
        })

        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'page-about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController',
            controllerAs: 'actrl'
        })

        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'page-contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController',
            controllerAs: 'cctrl'
        });
    })

    .controller('homeController', function(){
        this.pageClass = 'page-home'
    })

    .controller('aboutController', function(){
        this.pageClass = 'page-about'
    })

    .controller('contactController', function(){
        this.pageClass = 'page-contact'
    });
```

My problem comes when I use in in the `index.html`.

```
 <div class="page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div>
```

Since I'm not using `$scope`, just writing `{{pageClass}}` won't work. How can I get around this using the `controller as syntax`?

**Edit**

I got a couple of good answers. I also discovered an alternate way to do this if you want to name your `controllerAs` values with different names: `hctrl`,  `actor` and `ctrl` (like my code above):

You could do this in the html:

```
<div class="page {{hctrl.pageClass || actrl.pageClass || cctrl.pageClass}}" ng-view></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good approach towards this problem is by setting the `pageClass` as a configuration in the routes definition and then create a directive that gets these definitions to be applied as whatever you want them to be (of course within the scope where the directive is applied to).

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UylSxJ0a0xawLuT5QIJJ?p=preview)**

**Javascript**

*Define your route configuration with **data** key-value object.*

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'page-home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'hctrl',
            data: {
              pageClass: 'page-home'
            }
        })

        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'page-about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController',
            controllerAs: 'actrl',
            data: {
              pageClass: 'page-about'
            }
        })

        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'page-contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController',
            controllerAs: 'cctrl',
            data: {
              pageClass: 'page-contact'
            }
        });

  })
```

*Create a directive that sets these data with the directive's controller.*

```
  .directive('routeData', function() {
    return {
      controller: 'RouteDataController',
      controllerAs: 'RouteData',
      bindToController: true
    }
  })

  .controller('RouteDataController', function($rootScope, $route) {

    var self = this;

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', setCurrentRouteData);

    setCurrentRouteData();

    function setCurrentRouteData() {
      angular.extend(self, $route.current.$$route.data || {});
    }

  })
```

*In your index.html apply the directive itself and access the directive's controller to get the **data** values.*

```
<div ng-view route-data class="page {{ RouteData.pageClass }}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. By the way - Is my edit above a reasonable approach?

Comment: No, what would happen if you would add new routes? let's say 20 route additional routes. Would it be reasonable to add 20 more?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the controller as name

```
<div class="page {{hctrl.pageClass}}" ng-view></div>
```

Comment: but it won't always be that controller?

Comment: you can do the actrl.pageClass or cctrl.pageClass

Comment: so I have to pass all three in the html?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you wrote in the controllerAs value need to be prepended to the variable, like `{{actrl.pageClass}}`

Comment: does it matter if I name everyone just `ctrl` in the routing?

Comment: No, you can name it whatever you want because each template has a separate controller or scope if you will. I name then according to the controller `controller: 'HomeController', controllerAs: 'home' ` just for clarity

Comment: I called all of mine `ctrl` and in the html I wrote `<div class="page {{ctrl.pageClass}}" ng-view></div>` That worked great.